# Publish Visual Basic Window Form Application Online

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Is it possible to publish vb window form application online which can be run like a website?

If yes? Is there a website which I can publish it?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You could create an HTML application (.hta).

Answer (score 1):

No, its not possible to publish it on a website.

You need to convert your code to another language like ASP.net.

The reason why you can't use vb.net desktop appliction on a website is that a webbrowser can't understand the code you have written.

Comment: Explain why with details.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. You can't run an executable file to a website. You can create a .ta file (HTML application).

Once you have published your project it will be in .exe. Since your application is not web-based, it is not possible.

However, you could create a Web Application Project (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983453(v=vs.90).aspx). You can publish the Web application to a local or shared folder, to an FTP site, or to a Web site that you access by using a URL.

Comment: This is the accurate answer for your question.